# How to avoid UIToolbar tintColor to change UIButtonItem button color?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have added a blue UIBarButtonItem to a UIToolbar in my app and changed the tintColor of the toolbar to black. However, the button also turned to black. Any idea to avoid this ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this...

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    UIBarButtonItem *signup = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"SIGN_UP",@"") style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(createAccountFun)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =signup;
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant button color not type.

Comment: how you set the button color ?

Comment: I didn't set it. I just use UIBarButtonSystemItemDone.

Comment: whether this code worked for you? what you are getting now? what do you want as the output?

Comment: I added the toolbar to a keypad so I would like the toolbar tintColor to be black and the button to be black like on this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/3GpVX.png

Comment: see the updated answer... this works like the image you posted here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4420/discussion-between-trisha-and-stephane-kouakou)